# exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy when installing wso2 bam

Tags: installation, wso2, wso2-bam

I'm trying to install the wso2 bam 2.5.0 on my mac with the following env

> uname -a
>   Darwin MacBookProAlagna.local 14.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.0: Mon Dec 22 23:10:38 PST 2014; root:xnu-2782.10.72~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
>   java -version
>   java version "1.7.0_45"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

When I start it I get the following exception and the server doesn't start.
How can I fix it?
Thanks
Alberto

TID: [0] [BAM] [2015-01-28 14:49:22,414] ERROR {org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon} -  Exception in thread Thread[WRITE-localhost/127.0.0.1,5,main] {org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.xerial.snappy.Snappy
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.(SnappyOutputStream.java:79)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.(SnappyOutputStream.java:66)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.connect(OutboundTcpConnection.java:364)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundTcpConnection.run(OutboundTcpConnection.java:148)

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on Mac OSX and the solution is available [in this jira](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BAM-1515).